# Filter more than 3 criteria with wild card

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I'm able to filter with 1 or 2 criteria using wild card using some codes like below:

`[a1].CurrentRegion.autofilter 1, "*wine*", xlor, "*beer*"`

I'm also able to filter with more than 3 criteria using an array as argument:

`[a1].CurrentRegion.autofilter 1, Array("France Red Wine", "US Beer", "Japan Sake"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

But just found out I can't use the same way above to filter more than 3 criteria with wild card using something like:

`[a1].CurrentRegion.autofilter 1, Array("*wine", "*beer", "*sake"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Any ideas what's wrong with the 3rd code and how I can filter more than 3 criteria and at the same time also use wild cards?

Comment: That’s just how it is - max two wildcard arguments when using this method.  See for example this workaround https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/wild-card-unable-to-use-in-autofilter-array.917998/. Or maybe look at Advanced Filter

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the answer. It is very helpful in explaining the problem and shows I can do. One quick question, do you have any idea why in the workaround, dictionary (with only keys and no value) is used instead of a simple 1-dim array?

Comment: The dictionary is used as a fast method of extracting all unique values which match the wildcards.  You could instead use an array and do the extra work of re-sizing and checking unique values, but a dictionary is simpler here.