# Include a partial string match in an array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, advanced-filter

I'm trying to edit my VBA code to filter for multiple values (which already exist in my worksheet) and for partial matches to also be filtered. This is my current code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AB$9903").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Desktop", "Monitor", "Non-Standard Desktop", _
    "Non-Standard Notebook", "Notebook"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I would like to add in another criteria, like anything that contains the word "Headset". I tried adding in * Headset* to the array above but it did not work. I also tried creating a new chunk of code for just words containing 'Headset', and while it did filter for those cells, it only filtered for those.

I'm not really sure what other options I have. I checked other people's solutions but it looks like in their solutions, they're doing what I did above (filtering only for words containing that specific string). Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: I've tested with Criteria1:=Array("*Notebook*", "*desktop*") and it filters ok. try to remove the space in * Headset*

Comment: Filtering on wildcards limits you to two items in the array.  Recent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290907/filter-more-than-3-criteria-with-wild-card#comment126027554_71290907

Comment: @LuisCurado . thank you but unfortunately, it's not working on my end. The space in * Headset* was also since if I write *Headset*, it turned my text into italics rather than showing the asterisks.

Comment: @TimWilliams if Headset is my only wildcard, shouldn't it only count for one item in the array?  I'll keep looking for solutions, but thank you both for your comments.

Comment: You can have max 2 items with wild characters. If only one item is with wild characters, that already means that you can have max 2 items for the wild characters to have an effect. If you have more items, the complete wild character items will be ignored. You can tackle this in a few ways where the 'complications' will depend on what you want to do with the data e.g. look at it, copy it , delete it...etc. The simplest way is probably to use `AdvancedFilter` which requires you to have some cells for the headers and the filters. If you can share what the end goal is, I can write an example.

Comment: Decent workaround here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/wild-card-unable-to-use-in-autofilter-array.917998/

Comment: @Tim Williams: You say *decent*, does any improvement come to your mind?

Comment: @VBasic2008 - not really: looks nice and simple.  Maybe swap the nested loops so the inner once could short-circuit on a match?

Comment: ...and a refactor to make a method which takes range, column index and an array as arguments.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for the help! I saw @VBasic2008 code below and will test it later today. To answer your question about what I'm doing, say I have the following list. <br/> [headset, bluetooth headset, headset USB, monitor, notebook, electronic notebook, desktop, USB desktop, non-standard desktop] <br/> I want to filter my list so that only [headset, bluetooth headset, headset USB, monitor, notebook, desktop, non-standard desktop] appears.

Answer (score 0):

### Using AdvancedFilter When Many Criteria With Wild Characters

You can use the following...

```
With ActiveSheet
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    With .Range("A6:AB9903") ' with headers
        Dim DataRange As Range ' without headers
        Set DataRange = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        .AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, .Range("AD6").CurrentRegion
    End With
    Dim VisibleDataRange As Range ' without headers
    On Error Resume Next
        Set VisibleDataRange = DataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not VisibleDataRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Do what you need to do (copy, delete...), e.g.:
        Debug.Print VisibleDataRange.Address(0, 0)
    'Else ' no filtered data found
    End If
    ' Remove the filter.
    .ShowAllData
End With
```

... if you use the range `AD6:AD12` filled with the following:

```
COL15
=Non-Standard Notebook   
=Monitor
=Non-Standard Desktop  
=Notebook
=Desktop
*headset*
```

... where you will replace `COL15` with the header in `O6`. You will enter the values e.g. like this: `="=Monitor"` or `'=Monitor`.